# Kerberos, impersonate causes 500 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5, kerberos

Trying to get kerberos to work.

Looking at wireshark output, the windows username is passed to my test script, but when I turn impersonate on in IIS, I get a 500 internal server error.

The script is as follows:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net" %>
<%
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string downloadString = client.DownloadString("http://10.6.2.117/DEV/api/1.5.12077.001/en-GB/8/56/Incident/GetList?%24id=1&StartIndex=0&PageLength=10");

Response.Write(downloadString);
%>
```

I can access the url directly via a browser with no problems.

With impersonate turned off I get the following wireshark output (line 8 shows username):

```
"1","0.000000","10.21.4.3","10.6.2.105","TCP","66","59546 → 7001 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1260 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1"
"2","0.000092","10.6.2.105","10.21.4.3","TCP","66","7001 → 59546 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1"
"3","0.017328","10.21.4.3","10.6.2.105","TCP","60","59546 → 7001 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=262144 Len=0"
"4","0.019120","10.21.4.3","10.6.2.105","HTTP","404","GET /test.aspx HTTP/1.1 , NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE"
"5","0.104296","10.6.2.105","10.21.4.3","HTTP","1940","HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized , NTLMSSP_CHALLENGE (text/html)"
"6","0.123311","10.21.4.3","10.6.2.105","TCP","60","59546 → 7001 [ACK] Seq=351 Ack=1261 Win=262144 Len=0"
"7","0.123314","10.21.4.3","10.6.2.105","TCP","60","59546 → 7001 [ACK] Seq=351 Ack=1887 Win=261376 Len=0"
"8","0.125557","10.21.4.3","10.6.2.105","HTTP","624","GET /test.aspx HTTP/1.1 , NTLMSSP_AUTH, User: EMEA\xxxxxx"
"9","0.183273","10.6.2.105","10.21.4.3","TCP","3834","[TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]"
"10","0.203950","10.21.4.3","10.6.2.105","TCP","60","59546 → 7001 [ACK] Seq=921 Ack=3147 Win=262144 Len=0"
"11","0.203953","10.21.4.3","10.6.2.105","TCP","60","59546 → 7001 [ACK] Seq=921 Ack=4407 Win=262144 Len=0"
"12","0.203955","10.21.4.3","10.6.2.105","TCP","60","59546 → 7001 [ACK] Seq=921 Ack=5667 Win=262144 Len=0"
"13","0.204018","10.6.2.105","10.21.4.3","HTTP","2389","HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error  (text/html)"
...
```

With impersonate turned on, I get (line 4 - no username):

```
"1","0.000000","10.21.4.3","10.6.2.105","TCP","66","59648 → 7001 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1260 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1"
"2","0.000111","10.6.2.105","10.21.4.3","TCP","66","7001 → 59648 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1"
"3","0.018178","10.21.4.3","10.6.2.105","TCP","60","59648 → 7001 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=262144 Len=0"
"4","0.019833","10.21.4.3","10.6.2.105","HTTP","404","GET /test.aspx HTTP/1.1 , NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE"
"5","0.111015","10.6.2.105","10.21.4.3","HTTP","1466","HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error  (text/html)"
...
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well we got there in the end after much fiddling and with the involvement of half a dozen staff members.

So, in case it is of use to anybody else, here are some useful findings:

1. Ensure the FQDN is used for the all URLs i.e. both in the client browser, as well as the URL being called by the first web server to the second.
2. IIS Application Pool Settings:

   - Managed Pipeline = Integrated
   - Identity = ApplicationPoolIdentity (other options may also work)
3. IIS Authentication Settings:

   - Anonymous Authentication = Disabled
   - ASP .NET Impersonation = Enabled
   - Basic Authentication = Disabled
   - Forms Authentication = Disabled
   - Windows Authentication = Enabled

     - Advanced Settings:
     - Extended Protection = Off
     - Enable Kernel-mode authentication = Off
     - Providers: Must be in this order. Do not enable just the ‘Negotiate’ option.

       - Negotiate:Kerberos
       - NTLM

And finally, a different test script:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<%
// The service we wish to consume
string uri = "http://eu9992k8dvweb01.emea.world.net/DEV/api/1.5.12077.001/en-GB/8/56/Incident/GetList?StartIndex=0&PageLength=10";

//Create web request
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);  

//Create credential cache
CredentialCache myCredCache = new CredentialCache();
myCredCache.Add(new Uri(uri), "Negotiate", (NetworkCredential)CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials);

//Add credentials to web request
req.Credentials = myCredCache;
req.Proxy = null;

// create somewhere for the response to go
HttpWebResponse httpResponse = null;

// now use the request
try
{
    // get the requested page
    httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

    // output what was returned
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        Response.Write(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
finally
{
    // close the response object
    if (httpResponse != null)
        httpResponse.Close();
}
%>
```